# Proof involving matrix rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Let $A \in M_n$. Prove $r(A)=1$ if and only if there exist matrices 
$B=\begin{pmatrix}
b_1\\
b_2\\
\vdots\\
b_n
\end{pmatrix}\in M_{n1}$ and $C=\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 &c_2 &\ldots &c_n
\end{pmatrix}\in M_{1n}$ such that $A=BC$.

My attempt:

Let
$B=\begin{pmatrix}
b_1\\
b_2\\
\vdots\\
b_n
\end{pmatrix}\in M_{n1}$ and $C=\begin{pmatrix}
c_1 &c_2 &\ldots &c_n
\end{pmatrix}\in M_{1n}$ such that $A=BC$. 
Then $r(B)=1$ if $B$ is not a zero matrix, and $r(C)=1$ if $C$ is not a zero matrix. 
Because of the following theorem: 
$r(X)=r(Y)=n \Rightarrow r(XY)=n$ we can say
$r(B)=r(C)=1\Rightarrow r(BC)=r(A)=1$.

Now I'm not sure about the other direction... What is the assumption here, is it just $r(A)=1$? Or is it $r(A)=1$ and $A=BC$? And then what do we have to prove, that $B\in M_{n1}$ and $C\in M_{1n}?$ If so, then how do we prove that?

Comment: The assumption should just be that the rank of $A$ is $1$. Once that is there, this means all rows of $A$ are multiples of one non-zero row (call it the first row). Now can you express such a matrix as product of two vectors?

Comment: @AnuragA I'm not following you...Why are all rows of $A$ multiples of one non-zero row and how do you even write that?

Comment: Classical question solved for example in (https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140429064832AAi1o0t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption should just be that the rank of $A$ is $1$. Once that is there, this means all rows of $A$ are multiples of one non-zero row (call it the $i^{\text{th}}$ row). 
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} k_1\mathbf{u}\\ \vdots \\ \mathbf{u}\\ \vdots \\k_{n}\mathbf{u}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} k_1\\ \vdots \\ 1 \\ \vdots \\k_{n}\end{bmatrix}[\mathbf{u}^T].$$

Answer (score 2):

The other direction means that the assumption is simply that $r(A)=1$, and you have to prove that there exists a pair of matrices $B, C$ such that $A=BC$.

---

To prove that, you should start by proving that

1. $A$ has a nonzero row.
2. each row of $A$ is a scalar multiple of the nonzero row of $A$.

Once you have that, it's easy to find $B$ and $C$.